# is f riemann integrable on [0, 1]?

Tags: calculus, riemann-integration

If f(x) = 
0 if x is R \ Q

= 1/q if x = p/q; p,q belong to Z, g =/= 0, (p, q) = 1

Is f Riemann integrable on [0, 1]?

Comment: Welcome to math stackexchange! Thi is a common problem, so we would greatly appreciate it if you told us a little about what you know how to do,and what you have tried on this problem.

Comment: Relevant keywords: Thomae function, or "popcorn function." (This should generate quite a few matches in the search word, rightmost corner of your screen)

Comment: you can use Lebesgue criterion for Riemann Integrability, just find points of discontinuity and show that its measure is $0$

Comment: So many downvotes for a newcomer... That's not a warm and fair welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: In which points is your $f$ continuous?

Comment: It's continuous on the irrationals and integers, if I'm correct.

Comment: It is not continuous at the integers. Consider $1/n \to 0$.

Comment: So then if it's not continuous on the integers it can't be riemann integrable?

Comment: Continuity at integers is not at all related to Riemann integrability.